# How to update old version of TeXstudio in Windows 7?

Tags: texstudio, updating

I am using TeXstudio 2.3 the last two years. Now new versions are available. I want to update the old version. Is it possible to update without uninstalling the previous version? Is there any way to get updates automatically like windows update? Any one can guide me regarding the two versions 2.3 and 2.6 which will be better?

Comment: Download the new version here: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download I don't use Win bu I guess that if you change the folder to install it you could keep two versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply install a new version on top of an old.

It's not recommended to install two different versions in parallel, because they will share settings. While we guarantee, that older settings can be read by newer versions, we do not test for the reverse. If you really need two separate versions, go for the USB ones. They store the settings in the folder next to the executable.

We have an update checker in TXS for a while now. It will notify you about new releases. However, there is no such thing like an automatic installation.

Comment: I think Litun is actually asking how to update to a new version and preserve all the user preferences from the old on.  He isn't looking to have two versions installed simultaneously.  For what it's worth, I'm currently trying to update to 2.9.0 on OSX and I have the same question.  I think it's definitely standard for OSX applications to handle updates themselves (i.e., not requiring the user to uninstall the old version manually), so if TeXstudio requires manual intervention then this should be spelled out somewhere (e.g., in a ReadMe file, or on the "Download" webpage).

Comment: Note that a search for "TeXstudio" in the user's home folder turns up nothing, which suggests that deleting the old TeXstudio application and replacing it with the new version will erase all user preferences.  Hope that's not how it works...

Comment: On OSX, all user data are stored in `~/.config/texstudio`. You can simply replace the app with an updated version and it will continue using the same settings. See also https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored

Comment: Will that keep the old settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the recent version without system installation: Download the portable version marked as USB type. Sigur gave you the link in comment already: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download. Extract the ZIP file into a different folder than your existing installation and start the executable.

I do not know version 2.3, but I know, that version 2.6.6 (the recent subversion) is much better than 2.4, that I once tested. And also usually you do not have to uninstall the old version, when you perform an update, but you should see, whether some sort of a Readme file exists and tells a different story.